# Kotlin multiple filters in lambda, with different results

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I am new to Kotlin and have stumbled upon this simple problem. I have an event stream where I consume Login events like this:

```
        mystream.events
            .filter { event -> event is UserLogin }.collectLatest { event -> handleLogin(event) }
```

Now in the same stream, I could also receive a Logout event, which I also want to handle in the same manner - but by calling a different handling function.

I can duplicate the same lines of code to do the same for the Logout event as well, but instead is there a way to do it in the same lambda/block of code. Sort of like an if/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a when statement for this:

```
mystream.events.collectLatest { event ->
    when (event) {
        is UserLogin -> handleLogin(event)
        is UserLogout -> handleLogout(event)
        //...
    }
}
```